# BusyBox on persistent USB Livesystem

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, uefi, initramfs

I fiddled a bit with creating a Live USB stick for creating a [LFS](http://trac.clfs.org/wiki) system on my new computer. To make this easier I wanted to store some persistent data on it as well (settings, GCC, make and such things). I created following partitions (gpt):

```
sdb1 8 MiB unformattad label: none flags: bios_grub
sdb2 100 MiB FAT32 label: EFI flags: boot, esp
sdb3 2.00 GiB FAT32 label: BOOT flags:msftdata
sdb4 11.77 GiB Ext4 label: casper-rw flags: none
sdb5 1.00 GiB swap label: none flags: none
```

I used Ubuntu 16.04 in my last test the system has no optical drives. It runs the Live-Image fine as long as I don't boot it persistent.

The last outputs on the console are:

```
done.
Begin: Setting up autologin... ..done
Begin Disablig systemd's GPT auto generator... ..done
begin: Setting hostname... ... /scripts/casper-bottom/18hostname: line 23: can't create /root//etc/hostname: nonexist directory
/scripts/casper-bottom/18hostname: line 25: can't create /root/etc/host
/scripts/casper-bottom/07remove_oem_config: .: line 20: can't open '/root/usr/share/debconf/
(here is something missing I could recreate between reboots)
Begin: running /scripts/nfs-bottom ... done.
Begin: Running /scrips/init-bottom ... muont: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
done.
mount: mounting /run on /root/run failed: No such file or directoy
done.
run-init: current dirctory on the same filesystem as root: error 0
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
run-init: current dirctory on the same filesystem as root: error 0
run-init: current dirctory on the same filesystem as root: error 0
run-init: current dirctory on the same filesystem as root: error 0
run-init: current dirctory on the same filesystem as root: error 0
run-init: current dirctory on the same filesystem as root: error 0
No init found. try passing init= bootarg
```

Busybox shell

I needed several reboots to type all in my kvm switch, messed up the outputs after switching system back and forth (doesn't be problematic once I get a real shell or being under X, but during this stage it messes a bit, may be a better one would have done this, but the errors occurs even without the KVM switch.

I found new info on the Problem. During the manual installation the boot files later accessible in /boot/efi didn't go into the ESP as intented by me.

Comment: Needs more info: Use the busybox shell to `cat /proc/cmdline`, and post it as well. `lsblk` and `blkid /dev/sdb*` would also probably be useful. Correct some of the spelling in the output ("/etc7hosts" looks like you forgot SHIFT while you were transcribing).

Comment: here the output of: `cat /proc/cmdline` `BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinux.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubunutu.seed boot=casper verbose persistent ramdisk_size=4294967296 keyb=de locale=de_DE no_splash ---` and `lsblk` `/bin/sh: lsblk: not found` finally `blkid /dev/sdb*` `/dev/sdb: PTUUID="09a937a3-d655-4940-930c-62977d50e1f" PTTYPE="gpt" /dev/sdb1:PARTUUID="ac796038-d5de-477d-b889-024fa5f51a52" /dev/sdb2: LABEL="EFI" UUID="2951-0969 "TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="a4c9d8a5-f77d-405e-8ea2-ef44ad50636f" /dev/sdb3: LABEL="BOOT" UUID="2970-7DAB" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="fa553f90-ee08-4107-b139-e32a0a2fea5e"`

Comment: not pretty, bus basicly the same info as above, oly with the UUIDs. here the last 2: `/dev/sdb4: LABEL="casper-rw" UUID="6f5b3335-5396-4d16-aab5-ca23def9d19e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e71c5d5d-85cd-4372-98e2-f62034620e95" /dev/sdb5: UUID="60d3492b-166e-4ba6-88d0-a77Type="swap" PARTUUID="6cf037f6-ddee-4226-b3f9-268c8d6b3536"' Nothing unusual in the values for me so far.